# Reduce relations with Fibonacci function never terminates,

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, infinite-loop, abort

i have a reduce operation which includes Fibonacci function. but the problem is it never terminates, i tried some modifications, for example removing f1 in my relation. sometimes it works and at least it gives me an output. **but the relation itself MUST NOT change and i dont want** to modify the expressions. Could you help me what the problem is, seems it is a loop or something?
**This expression cause the problem f1*Fibonacci[1 + j - N], also f1*Fibonacci[j - N]]].**

NONE of the expressions must change, every single expression is needed and no add/remove/modification is allowed

```
Reduce[Exists[{i, f, j, f1, f2, N}, 
  i == iPP && f == fPP && j == jPP && f1 == f1PP && f2 == f2PP && 
   N == NPP && j >= N && iP == i + j - N && jP == N && 
   f1P == f2* Fibonacci[j - N] + f1*Fibonacci[1 + j - N] &&   
   f2P == f2 *Fibonacci[-1 + j - N] + f1*Fibonacci[j - N]]]
```

Comment: Reduce has the form: Reduce[expr, variables]. You do not specify any variables.

Comment: `N` has a predefined meaning in Mathematica and should not be used as a user-defined symbol.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to @DanielHuber, I found the issue.

```
Reduce[Exists[{i, f, j, f1, f2, N}, 
  i == iPP && f == fPP && j == jPP && f1 == f1PP && f2 == f2PP && 
   N == NPP && j >= N && iP == i + j - N && jP == N && 
   f1P == f2* Fibonacci[j - N] + f1*Fibonacci[1 + j - N] && 
   f2P == f2 *Fibonacci[-1 + j - N] + f1*Fibonacci[j - N]] , {fP, f1P,
   f2P, iP, jP}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]
```